# Is there a difference between function closure "}());" and })();

Tags: javascript

I detected I made an error and used "}());" instead of "})();" and the code worked just fine which is how it went undetected. I'm wondering if there is a difference? Due to copy and paste this error is in a lot of separate scripts which makes me worried but confused since ESLint didn't complain. I've tried to find an answer but google doesn't give any results when searching for "}());" and "javascript wrong function closure" gives results hinting that they are both the same, no difference.
The functions looks like this:

```
const fname = (function() {
   const cached_func = ...;
   return function(p1, p2) {
     ...
     return cached_func.apply(this, arguments)
  };
}()); <- The error
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the difference is that enclosing your `function` within `(` and `)` tokens causes your statement to return the said function, as if you called it by its name. Thus, you're able to append `()` and immediately execute it.

The following two statements produce the same result:

```
// 1
function myFunction(){
    console.log("1")
}
myFunction();

// 2
(function myFunction(){
    console.log("1")
})()
```

It is not possible to call a function immediately after its closing bracket, as it results in an `Unexpected token ')'` error:

```
function myFunction(){
    console.log("1")
}() // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

These two forms are identical in functionality. It's purely a stylistic choice which you prefer.

Further read [here](https://maximdenisov.gitbooks.io/you-don-t-know-js/content/scope_&_closures/function_vs_block_scope.html)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of wrapping a function in parenthesis "()" is to namespace and control the visibility of member functions.

It wraps your code inside a function scope.

Where as '()' followed by function declaration is to immediately invoke the function which is often called IIFE